# Truly baffled. Can a 3 year old question be answered by a different person, who fixed the other's environment?

Tags: discussion

So back in April 2013, user `codable` had a git-svn problem, [git-svn dcommit fail for "URL access forbidden for unknown reason"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138575/git-svn-dcommit-fail-for-url-access-forbidden-for-unknown-reason)

And just a few minutes ago, user `GET` fixed it by removing user `codeable`'s svn "simple" authentication file, which one would assume only existed on user `codeable` workstation.

It seems from the wording of the answer, that either `GET` and `codeable` are the same person, or something else equally odd is afoot.  I mean, was it really such a blocker that it was fixed only 3 years after being reported?  I don't have to tools to know, but it looks like someone is trying to game the system in some manner that I'm not aware.

Would anyone shed some light as to why such an odd bird came into view?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It doesn't look to me like it's the same person.  It looks more like someone else had the same problem and posted how they solved it.

That said, even if it is the same person (which I doubt), there's nothing wrong with what they've done, so long as neither account votes on the other's posts, which doesn't appear to have happened here.

Comment: That's fine by me.  I just wonder how someone could verify it fixed the problem above.  It is written in a style that asserts they've fixed the problem, not in a style that says "I encountered the same problem".  In fact, I don't know from the question how you could assert you encountered the same problem (although often assumption is king on these vague issues).

Comment: @EdwinBuck Clearly that users is confident that they have the same problem and that their solution fixed it.  I have no idea whether or not either of those assumptions are correct, or reasonable.  You could certainly argue that it's a bad answer if you feel either of those assumptions are flawed; if you do, feel free to downvote it.

Comment: Not worth the down vote in my opinion, just an odd enough occurrence to warrant some commentary.  Thank you for your insight, and I'm of the same mind.  It is likely a very confident person who wrote his reply as if he fixed the other's issue, when fixing a self-identified "same" issue on his machine.